# I cant make an stencil using texture painting

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am trying to use a stencil using an Alpha Mask so I can place a typography (png image) to a 3d model. I tried  it a few days ago an it was all fine however i made a new mesh and now its seems that I cant make it work.

I made two basic bsdf materials, along with a texture with 0 alpha level, the texture attached to the secondary material. The texture (material base color) is also connected with the fac of the Mix shader. The Brush is set as "Mix". I also checked to flip normals in case I have been painting on the inside of the model.

I dont know what else to try. When I click the left buttom of the mouse the color of the model gets a little darker, thats all. [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169442/simply-adding-an-image-to-mesh-uv-confusion/169452#169452 refer this link I guess your's is the same question. There's also a youtube tutorial for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnfTSXWF21 Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but then I realized, that my normals where flipped.
So to be able to draw with the stencil method, make shure that the normals of your mesh are oriented the right way (blue) or turn off backface culling in the brush settings (active tool and worspace settings > options > backface culling).

Answer (score 1):

There are two common methods to use a PNG as stencil on a model, and I think you're confusing the two together.

One is to use the alpha channel as Fac to choose which color (or material) to show; in this case, no texture paint is needed, and the location of the stencil will be decided by moving the UV, eventually using the possibility of multiple UV maps, creating one to be used exclusively for the material of the stencil zone.

[image]

The Other is to use the PNG image as a stencil in texture paint mode; in this case, the PNG has to be loaded into a texture, and this texture has to be loaded in the texture slot of the brush settings, while the material is simply the texture you painted, without any need of alpha channel. Remember to turn its mapping to "stencil" while painting and use the Right Mouse Button with Shift and Ctrl modifiers to move rotate and scale your stencil.

[image]

Comment: I am trying the second method you described. The texture uses a png, is on "stencil". I can see the brush, but when I rigth click in does not "paint". I followed a brief tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnfTSXWF21A

Comment: I migth use the method using the uv map, but I want to know why I cant make the stencil XD

Comment: Right click is for grabbing, left click will paint.

Comment: @joshsanfelici I am having the same problem. I get to the point where the stencil pops up but I can never get it to actually have any affect