# Simply adding an image to mesh (UV confusion)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates

I don't fully understand UV Mapping.

I imagine that the shapes that evolve from the flattened/cut open 3D object, are laid out on a 2D canvas which is the UV Map. You can draw on that canvas, add images and all the things that are within the shapes (unwrapped 3D object) are gonna be shown on the 3D model, where the shapes belong.
But as I understand now, The Map is basically one Image and you lay those shapes on top of that one image.

1. Can I put a second image on there on a specific island?
2. Can I create a separate UV map for unwrapping *only* a specific part of the mesh?
3. Is a new map created every time I unwrap the object? If yes, how can I mangage all those maps?
4. Does a texture without alpha always cover the whole 3D model?
5. When is a texture from a UV Map activated/rendered? Does that only work via the shader editor?

As an example, how would I put this white logo/lettering on this screwdriver, which I modelled in Blender? Assuming that I have the logo as an image file.

I use Cycles for that project.

[image: screwdriver with white logo]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to Blender.se. I believe your question may be borderline, but still valid for this site. (Thanks for taking the tour.) I have edited your question a bit and condensed it to only the most crucial information. Have I removed anything vital? If yes, please edit it back in again. Although this style of writing may seem impersonal, it will help others answer your question and find information more quickly.

Comment: As your question is also about shading (using textures in a material), it would help if you added the render-engine as a tag (EEVEE, Workbench, Internal, Cycles ...)

Comment: Thank you @Leander for helping me making my question more efficient! I added just a few words. Let's see what the community can do with it :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way of solving that problem is to

Firstly, Bake the Textures from the modeled object that you've created.

Select the 3d object.
And goto "Editmode" and mark seam <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>-->"Markseam" then <kbd>U</kbd>-->Unwrap. Then open your "UV Editor" to check your unwraped mesh.

If you have no knowleadge about unwrapping mesh without overlaping check out this links

[Painting a dog with texture paint, TOTAL NOOB](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168793/painting-a-dog-with-texture-paint-total-noob/168798#168798)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k

[image]

Now, create new Image for your unwrapped mesh to bake the textures in.
[image]

Now, goto "Shader Editor" and create new "Image Texture" Node by <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>--> Texture --> Image Texture.
[image]

Now, select the Texture Image that you've created for your mesh, in your newly created Image Texture Node. and Select the just the Image texture "node".
[image]

Goto the Scene and select Cycles Engine.
[image]

Now, goto the bake menu

[image]

Select the bake type --> Diffuse and just check the "color" option.

[image]

Now, goto "Object mode" and Hit "Bake" button under bake menu.

[image]

------------Wait for it to bake the texture.---------------

Now save your texture and open it in "Photoshop".
[image]

Now open both the saved texture file and the logo png file in Photoshop or other photo editing tools. In my case I've used Photoshop to add the logo to the texture.

Now, save the edited texture(or) image file.

[image]

Now, if you'd open the edited image/texture file into the blender and plug it to your mesh you'll see something like this.

[image]

But I've even created and added a Normal map of the diffuse map to get a bump effect of the logo.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Akai for the detailed answer!

The situation that I'm in is more like: I have the model, I built a material and haven't applied any texture to the object yet. Except a noise texture node, that I sent through a bump node to get that rough grainy texture that I want all over that material.
So I want the logo to not affect the whole surface of the material.

Would you approach this the same way?

Just then in photoshop make the background Alpha instead of green like you did? Or is there a more direct way?

Comment: how about using substance painter for texture creation and also adding the logo?
I always use it to create detailed and realistic textures.

Comment: I was actually just researching how other software would solve this. I found this video about substance painter. That's basically exactly how I imagine the solution. I select my image file and just paste it on the 3D object. Just like in this video at 2:30

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=160&v=SrSxTsIuX0M&feature=emb_logo

Is that not possible in Blender?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnfTSXWF21A ...Hope this helps you!

Comment: There you go! That's exactly the solution I imagined! Is there a reason why you would choose "your" method over that method? Is there a downside to the stencil method?

Comment: No there aren't any downsides. But it is simple than stencil.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's just a thing of preference it seems. 
Thanks for the help Akai!

Comment: You're Welcome! @JoshBadert

Answer (score 1):

So for everybody looking for a solution for that situation as well.
There are two ways (probably even more) to solve it:

1. The one that Akai explains in his post very detailed
2. The one that is explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnfTSXWF21A

Thanks for the help!